# vb 2010 web form sql data source not using all parameters

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, visual-studio-2010

In a VB.NET 2010 web form application. I want the user to be able to select various customers
    based upon if the first name, last name, or middle names are selected. The idea is for the user to select one, two, and/or three
    of the parameters and hit the search key.

The problem is the results only return data based upon only one parameter. If data for more than one paramter is selected, the  selection
criteria is ignored.
When I run the sql in sql server management studio, I get the results I want.

Thus can you tell me what I can do to solve the problem?

The code that is having the error is listed below;

```
<%@ Page Title="" Language="VB" MasterPageFile="~/MasterPage.master" AutoEventWireup="false" CodeFile="Support.aspx.vb" Inherits="letters_Support" %>
<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="MPHead" Runat="Server">   
</asp:Content>
<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="MPContent" Runat="Server">
<asp:Panel runat="server" ID="pnlSupport">    
<h3 style="text-align: center; border-style:none; ">Support Page</h3> 

  <table style="width: 100%;">          
      <tr>
        <td>
           Last Name: 
        </td>
        <td>
           <asp:TextBox ID="lname" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
        </td>
        <td>
            First Name: 
        </td>
        <td>
           <asp:TextBox ID="fname" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
        </td>
        <td>
             Middle Name: 
        </td>
        <td>
           <asp:TextBox ID="mname" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
        </td>
         <td>
            Search by Name:
        </td>
        <td>
           <asp:Button ID="btnSearch" runat="server" Text="Search" />
        </td>            
    </tr>
</table>
<br /> 
  <asp:GridView ID="GridViewSupport" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False"
    PageSize="25"
    GridLines="Both"
    EnableSortinAndPagingCallbacks="true"
    HeaderStyle-CssClass="ui-widget-header"
    PagerStyle-CssClass="ui-widget ui-widget-content"
    Width="100%" 
    EmptyDataText="No records were selected." 
    DataSourceID="sqlTEST" AllowPaging="True" AllowSorting="True" >
    <Columns>
        <asp:BoundField DataField="lastName" HeaderText="Last Name" SortExpression="lastName" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center" ItemStyle-CssClass="ui-widget-content" ControlStyle-CssClass="text required ui-widget-content ui-corner-all"/>
        <asp:BoundField DataField="firstName" HeaderText="First Name" SortExpression="firstName" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center" ItemStyle-CssClass="ui-widget-content" ControlStyle-CssClass="text required ui-widget-content ui-corner-all"/>
        <asp:BoundField DataField="middleName" HeaderText="Middle Name" SortExpression="middleName" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center" ItemStyle-CssClass="ui-widget-content" ControlStyle-CssClass="text required ui-widget-content ui-corner-all"/>
    </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
<asp:SqlDataSource ID="sqlTEST" runat="server" 
ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:sqlTEST %>" SelectCommand="SELECT [lastName] 
        ,[firstName]  
        ,[middleName] 
        ,[suffix]  
        ,a.[userid]
        from [TEST].[dbo].[Identity] 
          where ([lastName] like  '%' + @lname  + '%' and
               [firstName] like'%' + @fname + '%' and
       [middleName]  like'%' + @mname + '%') 
       or ([lastName] like  '%' + @lname  + '%' and
               [firstName] like'%' + @fname + '%'  and
               @mname is null)                  
       or ([lastName] like  '%' + @lname  + '%' and
               [middleName] like'%' + @mname + '%'  and
               @fname is null) 
           or ([firstName] like  '%' + @fname  + '%' and
               [middleName] like'%' +  @mname + '%' and
               @lname is null) 
           or ([lastName] like  '%' + @lname  + '%' and
               @fname is null and
               @mname is null) 
    or (@lname is null and
               [firstName] like'%' +  @fname + '%' and
               @mname is null) 
            or (@lname is null and
               @fname is null and
               [middleName] like'%' +  @mname + '%')    
           or (@fname is null and @lname is null and @mname is null)     
      order by  [lastName], [firstName], [middleName]" 
    CancelSelectOnNullParameter="false"  >
<SelectParameters>
    <asp:ControlParameter ControlID="lname" Name="lname" PropertyName="Text" ConvertEmptyStringToNull="true" />
    <asp:ControlParameter ControlID="fname" Name="fname" PropertyName="Text" ConvertEmptyStringToNull="true" />
    <asp:ControlParameter ControlID="mname" Name="mname" PropertyName="Text" ConvertEmptyStringToNull="true" />
</SelectParameters>
</asp:SqlDataSource>
</asp:Panel>
</asp:Content>
```

Comment: Could you clarify "If data for more than one paramter is selected, the selection criteria is ignored"? Does that mean: no records are returned? or all records are returned? or the wrong subset of records are returned?

Answer (score 0):

I imagine that having things like `@mname is null` in your query would mean that that part of the query only fires when a box is empty, in which case I'm stumped, but it could also be a brain fart. The bit where it says

```
@fname is null and @lname is null and @mname is null
```

looks a bit odd to me. You may have meant to put your field names in there.

Answer (score 0):

Possible problems that I see:

Your `asp:ControlParameter` do not have a `Type` declared, which defaults to `TypeCode.Object`. Try setting it to `String`:

```
<asp:ControlParameter ControlID="lname" Name="lname" PropertyName="Text" ConvertEmptyStringToNull="true" Type="String" />
<asp:ControlParameter ControlID="fname" Name="fname" PropertyName="Text" ConvertEmptyStringToNull="true" Type="String" />
<asp:ControlParameter ControlID="mname" Name="mname" PropertyName="Text" ConvertEmptyStringToNull="true" Type="String" />
```

Your query's logic is more complex than it needs to be. Try:

```
SELECT      [lastName]
            , [firstName]
            , [middleName]
            , [suffix]
            , a.[userid]
FROM        [TEST].[dbo].[Identity]
WHERE       ([lastName] LIKE '%' + @lname + '%' OR @lname IS NULL)
            AND ([firstName] LIKE '%' + @fname + '%' OR @fname IS NULL)
            AND ([middleName] LIKE '%' + @mname + '%' OR @mname IS NULL)
ORDER BY    [lastName]
            , [firstName]
            , [middleName]
```